# vertical slider HOME END key needs reversing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have some vertical slider widgets.
They have 1 at the bottom and 100 at the top.

I hit upArrow, PgUp keys and the
widgit moves up 1 or n units.

When I hit the HOME key which is on the same top row as the UpArrow and PgUp keys on the keypad
it moves down to 1 instead of moving up to 100.

The downArrow, PgDn, and END keys have the opposite effect.
ie: down 1 or n units, up to 100 instead of moving down to 1.

I think the horizontal slider is fine since the both HOME and END are both on
the 1st column.

Is there a way to change how these two keys (HOME and END) work for
vertical sliders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that Home and End keys on vertical slider working perfectly. Telerik team say on their's demo site:

> Home: Move the draghandle to the min value
>
> End: Move the draghandle to the max value

Anyway if you want to swap Home and End keys functions, this code will work for you:

```
$(".k-slider-vertical").on("keydown", function (e) {
    //HOME
    var slider = $(this).find('input').data("kendoSlider");
    if (e.keyCode === 36){
      slider.value(slider.options.max);
      slider._drag._updateTooltip(slider.options.max);
    }
    //END
    if (e.keyCode === 35){
        slider.value(slider.options.min);
        slider._drag._updateTooltip(slider.options.min);
    }
});
```

Here is working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/EPaYe